# C - execvp not working with valid input

Tags: c, exec

I have a program that takes in lines of commands from a file and tokenises them into char arrays:

Eg: the file contains:

> `ls -l -a -i`

and then in my program, I end up with this:

`char *cmd[10] = {"ls", "-l", "-a", "-i", NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL}`

and I'm calling

`execvp(cmd[0], cmd)` within a program using `fork()`.

But I'm getting a runtime error:

`ls: invalid option -- '
'
Try 'ls --help' for more information.`

from the command line.

I have tested this with a separate program that uses a hardcoded `char *[]` and it works fine.

**Edit:**
There is a `newline` character after the `-i`. I'll get rid of that. Thanks!

Comment: How does it tokenize the file in to the char *cmd[10] that you included?  Does your tokenizer write C code than you subsequently compile?  Or is that just a representation of what you think it tokenizes it to?  Given the error, my guess is that you're sucking the newline in to the cmd array somehow.

Comment: You didn't show the important code, which is how you're reading the command from the text file, but I suspect that when you're reading your file, you're getting the line feed at the end of the `-i` and `ls` thinks you're passing the line feed as an option. In other words, you're passing options `-l`, `-a`, and `-i\n`. Make sure you remove the trailing line feed. If you put in a debug `printf` that prints the options that you've parsed, you'll probably see an extra blank line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> ls: invalid option -- '
> '
> ```

The positioning of the apostrophes is suspicious. It seems as if the newline character somehow makes it into the array `cmd`, or perhaps into the last option. Maybe the string is not really `"-i"`, but actually `"-i\n"`. Check your parsing code.